# How to match comparison operators in Regex

Tags: regex

I'm trying to create a regex that matches comparisons like this:

```
= 445
> 5
>= 22
< 3
<= 42
<> 10
```

I thought that this would work, but it doesn't:

```
[=|>|<|>=|<|<=|<>]\s\d+
```

It's very important that the '>' or '<' precede '='. These operators would not be valid:

```
=<
=>
>>
<<
==
```

I'm using this to create some dynamic sql so the comparison operators need to valid sql.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 10):

```
(=|>|<|>=|<|<=|<>)\s\d+
```

or something like:
(doesn't really do what you want, it matches all 2character combinations of =<>, but for clearness)

```
[=><]{1,2}\s\d+
```

-> when you use the [] braces, it means, that one of the character inside should take place (multiple | defined may lead to undefined behavior, or behavior I'm not aware of)

-> you probably wanted to use simple braces (), where the | has the 'OR' meaning.

Comment: The second regex matches =>, == and =<.

Comment: You should add that the second version is just an approximation and matches things like >< and == as well.

Comment: Note that the second one matches some things the first one doesn't. eg: == >> << >< =< =>

Comment: This is really close but it also matches =< => which would be invalid. The < or > must precede the equals sign.

Comment: The second example was there only as example of using [] .. I had to flag it as 'not-exactly-what-you-wanted', sorry, corrected now.

Comment: The key is that the [] defines a character class- each unique character between brackets is a part of the class. The regex engine sees you defining a class with "=", ">", "<" and then you start repeating yourself. Whereas in the group you define with (), the regex engine treats multiple characters as you'd expect. I'd probably go with Yossarian's first option, as the second will match stuff like ">< 22" and "== 19" which you may not want.

Answer (score 4):

I would say the regex given by EmFi is good enough. With some modifications it can take expressions like this

```
"currentDate>=2012/11/07&&currentDate<=2012/11/08";
```

or this

```
"currentDate==2012/11/07";
```

With this modified regex

```
(<[=>]?|==|>=?|\&\&|\|\|)
```

And give it as "valid". Probably is very simple but at least in my case, enough

EDIT:
Regex was modified in order to take comparison operators (<,>,>=,<=,==) and boolean operators (&&,||) in a similar way to C-like languages

Comment: The question is one of matching rather than splitting. Could you update your answer so that it addresses the problem of matching the given comparison strings?

Answer (score 2):

The syntax `[…]` denotes a character class. Use `(…)` for grouping instead:

```
(=|>|<|>=|<|<=|<>)\s\d+
```

And here’s a more compact one:

```
(=|[<>]=?|<>)\s\d+
```

Or:

```
(=|<[>=]?|>=?)\s\d+
```

Answer (score 0):

This one will do what you're looking for.

```
(<[=>]?|=|>=?)\s\d+
```

Comment: That's horrible! Worse than APL!

Answer (score 0):

just solved this for myself.  it matches <, >, <=, >=, !=, =, <> and not => or =<  unfortunately it still matches >>.  I am just checking for that in my application code.

```
([!<>])?([=>])?(?!<)
```

Answer (score 0):

i'm now im hooray old post but, i've made regex witch is case sensitive and find only that what we need, and i hope it's help somebody.

Its works for != , <=, >=, ==, < , >  and find it only on the begining of string.

```
^(^(!=)?|^(<=)?|^(>=)?|^(==)?|^(<)?|^(>)?)?
```