# Regex for comparison operators

Tags: python, regex

I apologize for having to ask this and I suspect it's trivially simple to anyone even faintly familiar with regexes. I have a string that's always of the form: `comparison_operator integer`:

So for example `'>2:'` or `'<=0:'`.

I would like to just separate out the comparison operator and the number, but I have been unable to find a clear explanation on how to do this. Any help gratefully received. I'm using Python's **'re'** module although to my understanding regexes are more-or-less language independent.

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific problem you're having in a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: Why aren't *you* faintly familiar with regex yet? Have you tried to come up with a regex?

Comment: @CertainPerformance, Point taken, maybe, but I have actually looked around a fair amount for the solution to this - of the tabs I still have open:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2343938/how-to-match-comparison-operators-in-regex
https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

But the topic of regexes (as with any other programming topic) is a relatively complex one, the answers are not always obvious and I feel the question is still legitimate.

Comment: Instead of looking for a solution for this exact problem (which may or may not exist, somewhere, in a format usable for you), why not try to come up with a solution yourself? Based on what you've posted here, it should be pretty trivial.

Comment: @Aran-Fey, Yes! Here's a number of my failed attempts:
ipdb> re.search('><=',item[0])
ipdb> re.search('(<>=)',item[0])
ipdb> re.search('=',item[0])
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 1), match='='>
ipdb> re.search('(<[=>]?|==|>=?|\&\&|\|\|)',item[0])
ipdb> re.search('[<>=]',item[0])
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 1), match='='>
ipdb> re.search('<[=>]?|==|>=?|\&\&|\|\|',item[0])
ipdb> re.search('(<[=>]?|=|>=?)\s\d+', item[0])
ipdb> re.search('(<,>,=)', item[0])
ipdb> re.search('^\(\s*[a-zA-Z0-9_+\-\/* ]+\s*(>=|<=|>|<|==|!=)\s*[a-zA-Z0-9_+\-\/* ]+\s*\)$',item[0])

Comment: You said "comparison operators" in the question, but some of your regexes also match `&&`, `||`, `=` and `<>`. Do you really want to support all of those?

Comment: @Aran-Fey - no, I don't need to support those. That regex was taken from another stackoverflow question (linked above). I was just trying to get something working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `[<>]=?|==` to match the operator, and `\d+` to match the number. Enclosing each of those patterns in a [capture group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) will let you access the matched values:

```
>>> re.match(r'([<>]=?|==)(\d+)', '>2:').groups()
('>', '2')
>>> re.match(r'([<>]=?|==)(\d+)', '<=0:').groups()
('<=', '0')
```

You can also unpack the matched groups into individual variables:

```
match = re.match(r'([<>]=?|==)(\d+)', your_input)
operator, number = match.groups()
```